# Remove no coincidents from two ListProperty

Tags: java, iterator, listproperty

My goal is: Achieve two "identical" lists, removing non coincident objects from both of them in the less possible time.

What I've achieved: Two identical lists, removing non coincidents, but takes too long.

My problem is:

I have two big lists (800k records each), those lists are filled with objects (HashCode and Equals correctly implemented on those objects) and I need to delete the non coincident records on both lists. It could be only 3-100 records (nothing compared to 800k registers).

The problem is mainly performance, cause its taking 10+ minutes to do the operation.

This is what I've tried:

- retainAll: this works, but takes too long
- Using HashSet.retainAll: Can't use sets in my lists. It takes seconds, works wonderful, but I need duplicates
- Manually: one by one from list 1 looking in list 2, saving no coincidents in a third list, repeat operation backwards in a 4th list, then using removeAll with both lists.
- Iterators: looked like a good idea to copy lists, remove coincidences from both copied lists, this way I have less items each loop, and I only need to find once, because the remainings are non coincidents. Finally use removeAll to remove non coincidents from original lists, but still takes +-10 minutes.

I need to find a quicker way to do this, but can't figure it out.

About the duplicates: Sounds weird, but for my program 2 objects are equal if they have the same "name" but could have different values in other attributes that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not understanding all the reasons why you have equality on the name, but not the values.. or even how you determine if list A has "foo", and list B has 2x "foo" if you want to keep all "foo"...

Here is an idea.. Make a HashSet of "name" to array of objects of the same name... now you can use retainAll and then quickly reconstruct the original collection from the hashset values.

Comment: I'm parsing CSV Files which have stored readings from different water pumps each day. Each water pump, could read between 0 to 96 times per day. pumps with 0 readings, doesnt appear on the CSV file. Two objects are the same for me if they're the same pump (pump id), but they have different attributes (reading, time of reading). So, one of my routines compares readings from 2 different days, and some pumps may have not read one of those days, so I need to dump it.

About your idea, gonna try this, might be a good one.

Comment: Ok, so your answer was perfect. Created two hashset of strings with my "keys", did retainAll between both lists, then just an iterator to each of my main lists and remove the ones that weren't on the hashSets. Simple and beautiful. took 1 or 2 seconds to complete. Thanks!!!!